# Updating array item by index using Object.assign equivalent in spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, immutability

I have stumbled upon this gem recently while trying to update an index of an array;

What I tried is:

```
const a = [1,2,3];
Object.assign([...a], {1: 10}) );
// [1, 10, 3]
```

This allows me to programmatically update the a specific arrays items value, while not updating the original in one line.

However when I try to convert this to spread syntax:

```
[...a, ...{1: 10}]
```

It's not actually working, giving me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not iterable

Would I be correct in assuming that the object assign adds an iterable prototype to the object making the first option work, while the spread synatax is more generic and doest not include this feature?

Thanks

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not iterable` Error message says it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **spread syntax** expects an **iterable object**

> **Spread syntax allows an iterable** such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

The **Object.assign()** method expects an **Object** - it doesn't have to be iterable.

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties **from one or more source objects** to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

**Iterables**: https://javascript.info/iterable

So it seems it's quite the contrary to what you suggested: the **spread syntax** is less general than the **Object.assign()** method, as it requires a stricter type of items to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot spread objects like that. Refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax